# Display all rows into two columns

Tags: postgresql

I am having a View like this.

```
SemesterId  Course     Grade
1           course1     A
1           course2     B
1           course3     C
2           course4     D
2           course5     A
2           course6     B
2           course7     C
3           course8     D
3           course9     A
3           course10    B
4           course11    C
4           course12    D
```

I want to get result like below using postgre SQL.

```
SemesterId1 Course1 Grade1  SemesterId2 Course2  Grade2
1           course1  A             2    course4   D
1           course2  B             2    course5   A
1           course3  C             2    course6   B
                                   2    course7   C
3           course8  D             4    course11  C
3           course9  A             4    course12  D
3           course10 B
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: By copying your data to a (excel) spreadsheet with the desired layout.

Comment: @mikus I would have serious concerns about the approach Anusha takes - this definitely calls for implementation in presentation layer. But if we GO with SQL - I wonder - is it really something obvious I'm missing how to code this?

Comment: SQL returns rows, how you present them it's mostly your application or DB manager ala Management Studio. Now if you really want to dynamically modify the result columns, and fit all rows wihin several first ones.. well youre free to go, play with dynamic SQL or pivot tables, but neither I think its what the author asks for nor I can find any reasonable explanation to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of tasks should be solved on client side. However, it's also an interesting issue to solve in SQL.

```
select 
    sid1, course1, grade1,
    sid2, course2, grade2
from (
    select 
        c1.semesterid sid1, c1.course course1, c1.grade grade1, c1.rk, c1.rn,
        c2.semesterid sid2, c2.course course2, c2.grade grade2, c2.rk, c2.rn
    from (
        select *, dense_rank() over w rk, row_number() over w rn
        from courses
        where semesterid % 2 = 1
        window w as (order by semesterid)
        ) c1
    full join ( 
        select *, dense_rank() over w rk, row_number() over w rn
        from courses
        where semesterid % 2 = 0
        window w as (order by semesterid)
        ) c2
    on c1.rk = c2.rk and c1.rn = c2.rn
    order by coalesce(c1.rk, c2.rk), coalesce(c1.rn, c2.rn)
    ) sub

 sid1 | course1  | grade1 | sid2 | course2  | grade2 
------+----------+--------+------+----------+--------
    1 | course1  | A      |    2 | course4  | D
    1 | course2  | B      |    2 | course5  | A
    1 | course3  | C      |    2 | course6  | B
      |          |        |    2 | course7  | C
    3 | course8  | D      |      |          | 
    3 | course9  | A      |    4 | course11 | C
    3 | course10 | B      |    4 | course12 | D
(7 rows)
```

Comment: its a static solution, wont adapt to various number of rows (required columns)

Answer (score 0):

I don,t know why you do this this way, but you may use:

```
WITH tab_row_num AS (
    SELECT row_number() over (PARTITION BY "SemesterId") rn, "SemesterId" , "Course" , "Grade" FROM table1
),
joint_tab AS (
select
    t1_3."SemesterId" AS "SemesterId1", t1_3."Course" as "Course1" , t1_3."Grade" as "Grade1",
    t2_4."SemesterId" AS "SemesterId2", t2_4."Course" as "Course2" , t2_4."Grade" as "Grade2"
from tab_row_num t1_3
    full outer join tab_row_num t2_4
        ON (t1_3."SemesterId" = 1 AND t2_4."SemesterId"=2 AND t1_3.rn=t2_4.rn)
            OR (t1_3."SemesterId" = 3 AND t2_4."SemesterId"=4 AND t1_3.rn=t2_4.rn) 
)
SELECT 
    COALESCE("SemesterId1"::TEXT, '') , COALESCE("Course1"::TEXT, '') , COALESCE("Grade1"::TEXT, ''),
    COALESCE("SemesterId2"::TEXT, '') , COALESCE("Course2"::TEXT, '') , COALESCE("Grade2"::TEXT, '')
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT "SemesterId1" , "Course1" , "Grade1", "SemesterId2" , "Course2" , "Grade2"
        FROM joint_tab t
        WHERE (t."SemesterId1" = 1 OR t."SemesterId1" IS NULL) AND (t."SemesterId2" = 2 OR t."SemesterId2" IS NULL)
        ORDER BY "SemesterId1" NULLS LAST, "Course1" ASC, "Grade1" ASC, "SemesterId2" NULLS LAST, "Course2" ASC, "Grade2" ASC
    ) sub1
    UNION ALL

    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT "SemesterId1" , "Course1" , "Grade1", "SemesterId2" , "Course2" , "Grade2"
        FROM joint_tab t WHERE (t."SemesterId1" = 3 OR t."SemesterId1" IS NULL) AND (t."SemesterId2" = 4 OR t."SemesterId2" IS NULL)
        ORDER BY "SemesterId1" NULLS LAST, "Course1" ASC, "Grade1" ASC, "SemesterId2" NULLS LAST, "Course2" ASC, "Grade2" ASC
    ) sub2
) sub
```